# Xcode is saying my array is out of range but I can confirm that my array is not out of range

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an array I am using for my TableView Cell similar to a Facebook Feed. I successfully have been able to have my app's version of the Feed successfully show date of when the user made a post, show the user's email that created a post, show a photo uploaded with post but I can't seem to figure out how to make an array to their user Profile. All information is pulled from Firebase.

Below you can see a screen shot of my database structure.

Here you can see my Posts structure where I store the posts information.

> Posts > DocumentID > PostInformation (date, uploaded image url as string, poster email, like count as Int)

[Posts Database Struture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zq7K9.png)

tableview

I am trying to pull the user's profile from a different collection called Public.

> Public > UserEmail (test@gmail.com) > User's information (name, date, profile photo url)

[Public Database Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgyeV.png)

I got the post information from getting the information a Firestore Database and threw everything into an array.

Then I loaded everything into a tableview cell.

> //post variables
>       var userCommentArray = String

```
var likeArray = [Int]()

var userPostImageArray = [String]()

var userProfilePhotoArray = [String]()

var userPostDescription = [String]()

var PosterEmail = [String]()

var postDate = [String]()

var documentIDArray = [String]()
```

Above is my post variables

Below is my cell and the arrays used to load their information.

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let Cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "VidaFeed", for: indexPath) as! FeedCell
    print("Posteremail count = \(PosterEmail.count)")

   >> //Cell.userProfilePhotoFeedCellLabel.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: self.userProfilePhotoArray[indexPath.row]))
    Cell.FeedCellUserNameLabel.text = PosterEmail[indexPath.row]
    Cell.dateFeedCellLabel.text = "test"
    Cell.likeCountFeedCellLabel.text = String(likeArray[indexPath.row])
    Cell.postImageFeedCellLabel.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: self.userPostImageArray[indexPath.row]))
    Cell.postDescriptionLabel.text = userPostDescription[indexPath.row]

    if userPostImageArray[indexPath.row] == ""{
        Cell.postImageFeedCellLabel.isHidden = true
    }

    if userPostImageArray[indexPath.row] != "" {
        Cell.postImageFeedCellLabel.isHidden = false
    }

    return Cell
```

> > //Cell.userProfilePhotoFeedCellLabel.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: self.userProfilePhotoArray[indexPath.row]))

If I only comment out the profile cell then my app runs successfully, but it crashes whenever I add it back.

Below you can see where I tried to make sure my var userProfilePhotoArray wouldn't be out of my index range because I set it equal to a variable to limit going over the array range.

```
      if self.profilecount <= self.PosterEmail.count{
```

### self.profilecount = self.profilecount + 1

```
       func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return PosterEmail.count
}
```

---

```
    func getDatFromFirestore() {

let firestoreDatabase = Firestore.firestore()

    firestoreDatabase.collection("Posts").order(by: "Date" , descending : true).addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Connection Error")
        } else {
            self.userPostImageArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
            self.userCommentArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
            self.userCommentArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
            self.likeArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
            self.PosterEmail.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
            self.userProfilePhotoArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)

            for document in snapshot!.documents {

                self.dbread = self.dbread + 1

                print(self.dbread)

                let documentID = document.documentID

                self.documentIDArray.append(documentID)

                self.getUserProfilePhoto()

                if let postedBy = document.get("postedBy") as? String {

                    self.PosterEmail.append(postedBy)

                    let db = Firestore.firestore()

                    let docRef = db.collection("Public").document(postedBy)

                    docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
                        if self.profilecount <= self.PosterEmail.count{
                        self.profilecount = self.profilecount + 1
                        print("Profile count is \(self.profilecount)")
                        if let document = document, document.exists {
                            print(document)
                            if let userProfile = document.get("imageUrl") as? String {

                                self.userProfilePhotoArray.append(userProfile)

                                print("time = \(Date.self), \(self.userProfilePhotoArray).")


                        }
                    }
                }
            }

                if let postDescription = document.get("PostDescription") as? String {
                    self.userPostDescription.append(postDescription)
                }

                if let imageUrl = document.get("imageUrl") as? String {
                    self.userPostImageArray.append(imageUrl)
                }

                if let PostLikes = document.get("Likes") as? Int {
                    self.likeArray.append(PostLikes)
                }

                if let timeStamp = document.get("Date") as? Date {

                    let formatter = DateFormatter()
                    formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
                    let dateString = formatter.string(from: timeStamp)

                    let timeStampAsString = dateString

                    self.postDate.append(timeStampAsString)
                }

            }
            self.VidaFeed.reloadData()
        }

    }
}
```

Below is the output and I can clearly see that the array is equal to my PosterEmail array count and is it not going over but the app crashes whenever re add the cell for the user's profile image.

```
Posteremail count = 1
Profile count is 1
<FIRDocumentSnapshot: 0x6000001a2850>
time = 2020-06-01 03:00:28 +0000, "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/vida-clock-11690.appspot.com/o/UserProfilePhotos%2F8C2ADEC6-C108-4C70-8CDA-ADBFCC56B4E2?alt=media&token=1c2178b8-b35b-4e2a-bbc0-c7747843b673"].
```

I'm just stuck and nothing I have tired has worked so far. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Firebase` document will be fetched over network connection or a local disk cache, which means there are no guarantees on how long each API call takes. So, the `Firebase API` calls are always asynchronous. The first API call you have will fetch the `Posts` collection ordered by date, iterate through all the documents and append data into the `PosterEmail` array. It also appends data into `userProfilePhotoArray` array, but note that this is done through a different API call, which means it is done asynchronously. However, you are calling `reloadData()` method on `VidaFeed` before the second asynchronous call is completed - the one that populates `userProfilePhotoArray` - which means the count in `PosterEmail` and `userProfilePhotoArray` are not the same.

One way to solve this is by adding `self.VidaFeed.reloadData()` within the `docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in ... }` as well:

```
        docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
          if self.profilecount <= self.PosterEmail.count{
            self.profilecount = self.profilecount + 1
            print("Profile count is \(self.profilecount)")
            if let document = document, document.exists {
              print(document)
              if let userProfile = document.get("imageUrl") as? String {

                self.userProfilePhotoArray.append(userProfile)

                print("time = \(Date.self), \(self.userProfilePhotoArray).")

                // Add this line. 
                self.VidaFeed.reloadData()
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

This ensures that the `VidaFeed` will be notified every time a new item is added to `userProfilePhotoArray`.

Now, in `cellForRowAt` method, replace

```
Cell.userProfilePhotoFeedCellLabel.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: self.userProfilePhotoArray[indexPath.row]))
```

with

```
if indexPath.row < self.userProfilePhotoArray.count {
    Cell.userProfilePhotoFeedCellLabel.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: self.userProfilePhotoArray[indexPath.row]))
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Now the user's profile photo is correctly showing the correct user's profile photo. I"ll be sure to reload the data when making two different calls to the Firestore to avoid having this issue again. Thank you very much.

Comment: @IrvingGonzalez This is a great answer but just one clarification/correction; *This ensures that the VidaFeed will be notified every time a new item is added to userProfilePhotoArray* is not correct here. docRef.getDocument gets the document one time only so vidaFeed will only be updated when that function is called and not when a new item is added. Using [addSnapshotListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) on the parent collection will ensure that when a new item is added the tableView would be refreshed. Upvoted otherwise.